# How to call pause() function of NgbCarousel on ngOnInit in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

I am new to angular and using ngbootstrap for my ui. I am unable to load NgbCarousel in pause mode by default. Below is code which i have tried

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { NgbCarousel } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-dashboard',
      templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
      providers: [NgbCarousel] // add NgbCarouselConfig to the component providers

    })
     export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private auth: AuthService, private ngbCarousel: NgbCarousel) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.ngbCarousel.pause();
    }
    }
```

below is html file :

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-9">
        <ngb-carousel>
          <ng-template ngbSlide>
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=1" alt="Random first slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>First slide label</h3>
              <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template ngbSlide>
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=2" alt="Random second slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Second slide label</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template ngbSlide>
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=3" alt="Random third slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Third slide label</h3>
              <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
        </ngb-carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But pause is not working i am not getting any error. Is this the right way of calling pause method. Please guide me .

Comment: According to the [docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api#NgbCarousel), `NgbCarousel` **is a component and not a provider.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: Please use the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook as this hook is called *after* the component's views are initialised (see the [lifecycle hooks documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence) from Angular for more info):

```ts
import { AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
// ...
export class DashboardComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('carousel') carousel: NgbCarousel;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.carousel.pause();
  }
}
```

---

1. Remove the `NgbCarousel` as a provider on your component, since according to the [docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api#NgbCarousel), `NgbCarousel` is a **component** and **not** a **service**:

   ```ts
   @Component({
     selector: 'app-dashboard',
     templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
     // Remove providers array
   })
   ```
2. Add a template reference on the `<ngb-carousel>` element and use a `ViewChild` with the template reference as the selector, then call `pause` on the `ViewChild` instance:

   ```html
   <ngb-carousel #carousel>
     <!-- ... -->
   </ngb-carousel>
   ```

   ```ts
   import { AfterViewInit, /* OnInit */, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
   // ...
   export class DashboardComponent implements AfterViewInit {
     @ViewChild('carousel') carousel: NgbCarousel;
     ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.carousel.pause();
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: i added ngb-carousel #carousel i html and   @ViewChild('carousel') carousel: NgbCarousel in my component file but pause is not working

Comment: there is no error object is correctly imported the way u have mentioned but i have set interval as -1 to pause the caurosal and pause call method is not working

Comment: @Edric `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of undefined` id is set to `<ngb-carousel #carousel>`

Comment: @godblessstrawberry Sorry for the long wait, but could you try using the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook?

Comment: @Edric Wish I would've seen your comment I spent 15-20min with `this.carousel` coming up undefined because at that point in the lifecycle it hadn't been defined yet. `ngAfterViewInit` worked for me!

Comment: In my case, the problem was that I used `@ViewChild('carousel', {static: true}) carousel: NgbCarousel;`. It works without `{static: true}`

Answer (score 4):

To freeze the carousel from the start, set the interval to 0.

You can do this on the HTML:

```
<ngb-carousel #carousel interval="0">
```

Or in the constructor:
You will need to import NgbCarouselConfig from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap', use it in the @Component decorator as a provider.
Importing NgbCarousel will be no longer needed for this purpose.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbCarouselConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
  providers: [NgbCarouselConfig] // add NgbCarouselConfig to the component providers

})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(config: NgbCarouselConfig) { 
        config.interval = 0;
    }

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```